# How to improve the accuracy of ner of StanfordCoreNLP?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I used NER of StanfordCoreNLP to recognize the entity including organization, location and person. But there exists something weird. **For example, I input a sentence like "Cleveland Cavaliers" and it will recognize the 'Cleveland' as 'location' but not 'Cleveland Cavaliers' as organization.** 
I am not very familiar with the ner and I don't know how the NER works. My task is to get all the company name in the text and the result I have got is not very satisfactory. So there are two ways occuring to me to solve the problem. The first is to modify the dict and insert the correct data. The second is to train the model. But there are still some questions.

1. Will the first way work effectively?
2. If the answer of question 1 is yes, how to modify the dict?

Further more, the FAQ list at https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a proposed the way to train the ner model but what confused me most is **what I will get if I trained my model.**

3. If I create a dataset containing like

   "organization 'Cleveland
       Cavaliers'"

   to train the model, what will happen in the model? The dict inside the CRFClassifier will change?
4. Will the CRFClassifier modify the bug when I input 'Cleveland Cavaliers' and recognize the 'Cleveland Cavaliers' as an organization entity?

These are all my puzzles and I am preparing the dataset to try the second way. Can anybody answer the 4 questions above? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the first solution is not very technical and every time you want to tag a new company, you need to update your dictionary.
I prefer your second solution and I do this before and trained a new model to tag my sentences.
If you have a good corpus that is big enough which tagged properly, It may take some time to train, but it worth the effort.